# Log User Session Activities Using Triggers

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to use triggers to log all the user session activities. What I have is this

```
CREATE TABLE User(
EmployeeID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (EmployeeID));

CREATE TABLE LogActivity (
  LogDateTime DATETIME NOT NULL COMMENT 'Date and Time of Activity',
  LogActivity VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'Activity : Insert / Update / Delete',
  LogTableName VARCHAR(45) NULL COMMENT 'Table Activity\n',
  LogDetail VARCHAR(255) NULL COMMENT 'Detail of the activity',
  LogUser VARCHAR(10) NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'User who do an activity.',
  PRIMARY KEY (LogDateTime,LogDetail))
COMMENT = 'This table keeps activities of users';

DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER log_insert_item
AFTER INSERT ON Item
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO LogActivity (LogDateTime,LogActivity,LogTableName,LogDetail)
    VALUES (NOW(),'INSERT', 'Item', CONCAT('NEW ROW : ',NEW.ItemID));
    UPDATE LogActivity SET LogUser = User.EmployeeID FROM (SELECT Max(EmployeeID) FROM Store.User);
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

But the code does not even run. I had a working version using current_user, but what it logged was the root user. What I want is to log the EmployeeID using that session.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (That code is product specific.)

Comment: @jarlh I am running a mysql database. Also, this is the code that I managed to get working, but it is not the desired effect that I want. I want to replace the current_user with the user id using the session. Code: DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER log_insert_item
AFTER INSERT ON Item
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
 INSERT INTO LogActivity (LogDateTime,LogActivity,LogTableName,LogDetail,LogUser)
    VALUES (NOW(),'INSERT', 'Item', CONCAT('NEW ROW : ',NEW.ItemID),current_user);
END$$
DELIMITER ;